# mod_rewrite is redirecting instedad of rewriting

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain

I must be missing something obvious, but I can't make it work

I want to have nice urls with subdomains, but instead of some directories I want to read the subdomain's content from the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/subdomain.php
```

These rules works, but if I enter subdomain.example.com I am *redirected* to example.com/subdomain.php - but I do not want this, I just want internally rewrite the url...

Thank you very much! I tried [QSA, L], do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/subdomain.php
```

With this, I suspect it will work as you are expecting:

```
RewriteRule (.*) subdomain.php
```

There is no need to rewrite the domain unless you actually want to redirect to another domain, you only need to rewrite the request to point to the appropriate file. Indeed as you discovered rewriting the domain will cause a redirect. Normally RewriteRule matches all of the request after the domain, so just the path and query.

Comment: Great! Now it is better:) But classical syndrome, now do not works images, css... I suspects that the first rule

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com

is rewritting everything, I tried to limit it with $ symbol, but no success.

Comment: You would need to either add a RewriteCond to exclude the files you don't want rewritten or change the RewriteRule regex to match those files you do want rewritten. The answer from Chris below includes some good RewriteCond's for excluding files that exist.

Comment: it seems %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} does the trick! I will experiment with it more

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use mod rewrite for this, if you have access to the DNS controls of your domain, you could set a catchall subdomain with a wildcard (either '%' or '*') that directs to the same local directory. There, you could have a PHP script which all requests are directed to using:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

and this would run all the requests into that PHP file. There you can have something that checks the $_SERVER variables for the requested domain, and a checker to see the subdomain. There it could use something such as a file_get_contents() subroutine to forward the relevant data to the client, and have 404 or 403 header responses if a request is made that may be valid, but not to that subdomain.

hope that makes sense...

Comment: I need just few subdomains, your generic solution is great for more. Thanks

Comment: Its the one I use. I used a similar system to deviant art for easy viewing of user profiles. You just go to http://$USERID$.mydomain.com/ and it automatically goes into the script and goes from there. If you also have static content, such as css or images, you can upload them there and the !-d and !-f make sure that the script doesn't try to run when there are real files trying to run.